# How to add several columns to a database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

Hi I just created a database in RoR. I now want to add 10 more columns to it. However, I dont want to use the following type of command that adds only 1 column at a time:

```
rails generate migration AddClosing_Hrs1ToBusinesses closing_hrs1:string
```

Is there a way to add multiple columns to my database without having to type a command for each column individually like above?

Comment: Not sure what changes have been made to Rails migrations since a few years ago... but, when I used to make a lot of column changes, I used to write the changes manually into the migrations/schema file and then run the file.  See Migrations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify your column names all in one go

```
rails generate migration AddClosing_Hrs1ToBusinesses closing_hrs1:string new_cloumn:string third_column:string
```

Documentation : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html