# How do I create a model with many fields on rails? Two fields should have options to choose from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I want to create a model with many fields on rails. I want two of the ten fields to have two or three options to choose from to check off.

The guide I'm using has only two fields, as follows:

```
rails generate scaffold topic title:string description: text.
```

It seems like the easy way out is to do a migration in this format:

```
rails generate migration AddClosing_Hrs1ToBusinesses closing_hrs1:string new_cloumn:string third_column:string
```

(source: [How to add several columns to a database in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550181/how-to-add-several-columns-to-a-database-in-rails)).

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where you are in the process.

If you have not yet created the model at all you can just add more fields to the original generate scaffold line. For example if you wanted 4 fields:

rails generate scaffold topic title:string description:text another_item:string some_number:integer

If you already created the model but have not yet run rake db:migrate then you can find the migration file in app_name/db/migrate/. Open the file and add lines for your new fields

If you have already run db:migrate then you should follow the answer for "How to add several columns to a database in Rails" that you linked in your answer.

For the fields where you want several options to select from those options will need to be handled by a combination of your model and view code. Assuming the options will stay constant and you can only select one first define the options array in your model using something like:

OPTIONS_FOR_TITLE = ["Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3"]

Then in the view code you will use the select and options_for_select helpers to create the view. More details on them are available here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#the-select-and-option-tags

For lots of detailed information about migrations:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html